# Angular - prevent ngOnInit call after URL change with hash

Tags: angular

I am new in Angular and I met problem I cannot solve with any solution.
I'm building my first app which is going to be similar to Google Photos just working in LAN and serving photos from PC.

Short description of my problem:
I've created working directory and photos explorer, having a component which sends request to server with current path, and receives list of directories and photos withing that path that are displayed to user in my app - navigation up and down and displaying grid of photos work as expected.
Now I wanted to link some library which will display photos in some pop-up and allow some photo slideshow.
I found e.g. that library: https://nextapps-de.github.io/spotlight/

The problem I find, is that when I try to open photo that library (and the other I found as well) add something to URL e.g. #show or #slideshow what makes my page to reload (I mean my Component is recreated and ngOnInit is called again which results that requests to server are sent again...).

I guess it's connected with my route:
`path: 'photos', children: [ { path: '**', component: PhotosComponent } ]`

It's the only way I managed to make it work as I don't know exact route (which is dependent on directory structure where photos are kept).

Does anyone have any idea how to make it work, to stop calling ngOnInit every time url location changes (with #something)? Or is there any other solution for my problem.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to try adding this to your RouterModule import (in app.module):

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true, onSameUrlNavigation: 'ignore'})
```

Comment: Nice! It's seems to work now, I've tried some configuration with useHash and onSameUrlNavigation but apparently not in such combination. But .. although it works there are errors printed to console such: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'spotlight' / 'show' after trying to open photo in Spotlight gallery, can they be somehow ignored?